# Dataframe transformation - how to save memory?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{'id': 'Jones', 'tf': [(0, 0.5), (1,2.0)]},
        {'id': 'Alpha', 'tf': [(1,2.0)]},
        {'id': 'Blue', 'tf': [(2,0.1),(1,0.2)]}]
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

`
I want to have dataframe in this form:

```
'id', 'var', 'value'
Jones, 0, 0.5
Jones, 1, 2.0
Alpha, 1, 2.0
Blue, 2, 0.1
Blue, 1, 0.2
```

I can do it in two steps:

i) unnest to form: id,0,1,2 - columns

```
id   ,0  ,1  ,2
Jones,0.5,NaN,2.0 
Alpha,NaN,2.0,NaN
Blue ,0.2,NaN,0.1
```

ii) melt with id

But there is a problem with step i). My dataset is rather sparse so **unnesting takes a lot of memory** for NaNs.

I'm looking for pandastic solution that avoids unnesting and it is memory efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be fast

```
s=df.tf.str.len()
t=pd.DataFrame({'id':df.id.repeat(s),'V':df.tf.sum()})
t[['var','value']]=pd.DataFrame(t.V.tolist()).values
t
Out[550]: 
          V     id  var  value
0  (0, 0.5)  Jones  0.0    0.5
0  (1, 2.0)  Jones  1.0    2.0
1  (1, 2.0)  Alpha  1.0    2.0
2  (2, 0.1)   Blue  2.0    0.1
2  (1, 0.2)   Blue  1.0    0.2
```

Comment: Thanks for help!
Last line  t[['var','value']] = pd.DataFrame(t.V.tolist()).values gives me error:
KeyError: "['var' 'value'] not in index"

Comment: I highly recommend replacing `df.tf.sum()` with `list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(df.tf.tolist())`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ yep , I need to keep that in mind , thank you man : -) remind me twice today :-)

Comment: Fix but not nice:

    t['var'] = pd.DataFrame(t.V.tolist()).values[:,0]

    t['value'] = pd.DataFrame(t.V.tolist()).values[:,1]

Comment: No problem. Either that, or `[list(j) for i in df.tf.tolist() for j in i]`, will do the same thing, and are equally fast (list comp may be faster).

Comment: @Wen, COLDSPEED Do you recoommend any book/blog where I can find methods like this?

Comment: @QuantChristo ummm this more related to experience , if you got those kind of question , you can not solve by yourself, you can always post here, one of us will definitely help you out

Comment: What do you think about this version?

    `s = df['tf'].str.len()`

    `tf = sum(sum(list(df['tf']), []), ())`

    `t = pd.DataFrame({'id': df['id'].repeat(s),'var': tf[::2], 'value': tf[1::2]})`

Answer (score 0):

This is the loopy way. It will not be fast, but requires minimal memory.

I use `.iat` for fast integer-based lookup, so care is required if you have other columns in your dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

data = [{'id': 'Jones', 'tf': [(0, 0.5), (1,2.0)]},
        {'id': 'Alpha', 'tf': [(1,2.0)]},
        {'id': 'Blue', 'tf': [(2,0.1),(1,0.2)]}]

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(columns=[0, 1, 2]))

for idx, lst in enumerate(df['tf']):
    for tup in lst:
        df.iat[idx, tup[0]+2] = tup[1]

df = df.drop('tf', 1).melt('id').dropna(subset=['value'])

#       id variable value
# 0  Jones        0   0.5
# 3  Jones        1     2
# 4  Alpha        1     2
# 5   Blue        1   0.2
# 8   Blue        2   0.1
```

Comment: Thanks, but extracting column names could be a pain and separate question itself ;-)

Comment: I think it uses a lot of memory. Just look df before last line, it has a lot of NaN.

Comment: By that logic the code should blow up at `df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(columns=[0, 1, 2]))` - `NaN` everywhere, but I'm not sure that's the case.